# The media player doesnt play the next song from the listView but when i show a message box with the url of the song then the song plays

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, random

i have this code

```
 If AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.playState = WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsStopped Then
            tempInt = gen.Next(0, listTracks.Items.Count - 1)
            currentTrack = tempInt
            If tempInt = playedBefore Then
                tempInt = gen.Next(0, listTracks.Items.Count - 1)
                currentTrack = tempInt
                AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = listTracks.Items(tempInt)
            'here > MessageBox.Show(AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL)
                AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play()
                playedBefore = currentTrack
            Else
                currentTrack = tempInt
                AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = listTracks.Items(tempInt)
            'here > MessageBox.Show(AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL)

                AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play()
                playedBefore = currentTrack
            End If
```

When the song ends the next songs doesn't play.But when i display the url of the song to a message Box then it plays(marked at the code)

Comment: Use source code comments to point at something inside the code.

Comment: your comment doesnt help me with what i have asked

Comment: Please provide your question in cleaner form, you are stating the facts about your program as it currently stands. Unluckily I'm unable to help you as I'm not proficient in vb.net, just pointed out one of the reasons why you may not receive appropriate attention.

Comment: So if you un comment the line that shows the message box, it plays. Right?

Comment: yea,if i uncomment the line it will play

Comment: I would guess this is related to thread changes/event loop but I can’t say for sure. Maybe start all of the player interactions in a different thread?